# Why does to_categorical of 0 equal [1,] and not [1,0]?

Tags: keras

Whenever I try the `to_categorical`function in keras, it always outputs [1,] even though I want [1,0]. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Keras cannot know the number of classes you have. If you pass only a single 0, it assumes that there is only one class.
To solve your problem, use:

```
to_categorical(0,num_classes=2)
```